# Spring application connecting to Database

Tags: java, database, spring

Any one tell me how to connect to database using spring application.

Answer (score 1):

Use Hibernate as ORM tool, and use Spring ORM support that would be a *good design*.

**See also :**

- [Object Relational Mapping (ORM) data access](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)
- [Sample application](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html)

Comment: Why does everybody link to ancient versions? Replaced 2.0 link with 3.0 version

Answer (score 0):

First You have to make enteries for Data Source in application context.xml.

Then we have to make a entry in context.xml and we have to provide the database credentials and location in context.xml

I am attaching both the files of my project.

Hope it may help you.

**Code For Application Context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

        <bean id="messageSource"
         class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
                <property name="basenames">
                        <list>
                                <value>report/cobReports_message</value>
                        </list>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <context:component-scan
                base-package="com.jpmc.am.architecture.emailaddrutil, com.jpmc.am.architecture.cob" />

        <bean id="multipartResolver"
         class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
                <property name="maxUploadSize" value="200000" />
        </bean>


        <bean id="sqlMapClientTemplate" 
         class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate">
                <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sqlMapClient" 
         class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
                <property name="configLocation"
                 value="classpath:sqlMap/cobSqlMapConfig.xml" />
                <property name="dataSource" ref="cobDataSource" />
                <property name="useTransactionAwareDataSource" value="true" />
                <property name="sqlMapClientProperties">
                 <value>COB_SCHEMA=CLTAPPMGR //////// Database Schema Name</value>
                </property>
        </bean>

        /// Data Source Name
        <bean id="cobDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
          <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/cob" />
        </bean>
</beans>
```

**Code For Context.xml**

```
<Context>

 <Resource name="jdbc/cob" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
 factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
 driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
 url="database location:databasename"
 username="username"
 password="password"
 />




</Context>
```

Comment: I edited the context for you. No need to add all those XSD namespaces (task, util, p, jdbc, j2ee etc.) if you don't use them!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Spring JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) and the JdbcTemplate which is probably the fastest and simplest route.

Agreed with above to look at an ORM solution for anything beyond the basics.